# sql query - how to filter results from last hour?

Tags: sql

I would only like to get only the data from the last hour. the query should be something like that...

```
SELECT some_date_related_data FROM some_table
WHERE time > now() - (1hour)
```

how can i achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Which date functions you have available depend on your database software.

Comment: `WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

Comment: It's likely to be a MySQL question, considering he's using `NOW()`

Comment: @ypercube, that's less likely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql

Comment: @Lucas: Yeah, I agree. It's also less likely because many Access users tend to use the QBE window and not SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you used `NOW()`, I'm guessing this is about MySQL. Then I'd suggest reading the manual :-)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

---

For **MySQL**:

```
WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ;
```

or

```
WHERE time > DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR ) ;
```

---

For **MS-Access**:

```
WHERE time > DateAdd( 'h', -1, Now() ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's MSSQL it'll be:

```
DateDiff(hh,time,GetDate()) < 1
```

Or mySQL, you'll find the altfernative here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` returns you a timestamp, so you can use it in following way:

```
SELECT some_date_related_data FROM some_table
WHERE time > ( now() - 3600 )
```